# Ao logar o form_validation não valida como o esperado

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

Estou começando com codeigniter, mas estou com um probleminha: Ao logar, ele não sai do if de senha e e-mail incorretos. Os campos do formulário estão corretos e do banco.

Podem me ajudar?

Esse é o controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class login extends CI_Controller {

    public function entrar(){

        $mensagem = null;

        if($this->input->post('acessar') === 'acessar'){

             $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'email', 'required|valid_email');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha', 'senha', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[40]');

             if($this->form_validation->run() === true){

                $this->load->model('LoginModel');

                $email = $this->input->post('user');
                $senha = md5($this->input->post('senha'));

                $loginExistente = $this->LoginModel->verificaLogin($email,$senha);

                if($loginExistente === true){

                    $usuario = $loginExistente;

                    $session = array(
                                'user' => $usuario['email'],
                                'nome' => $usuario['nome'],
                                'logado' => true
                                );

                    $this->session->set_userdata($session);

                    redirect('administracao/index');

                }else{

                    $mensagem = array('class' => 'danger',
                                    'mensagem' => 'Login inválido, e-mail ou senha incorretos.'.$email.' '.$senha
                                );

                }

             }else{

                $mensagem = array('class' => 'danger',
                                    'mensagem' => 'Foram encontrados erros no login </br>'. validation_errors()
                                );
             }
        }

        $dados = array('alerta' => $mensagem);

        $this->load->view('login/index', $dados);
    }

    public function sair(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        redirect('login/entrar');
    }

}
```

Esse é o model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LoginModel extends CI_Model {

    public function verificaLogin($email,$senha){

        $this->db->from('useradmin');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('senha', $senha);
        $usuario = $this->db->get();
        print_r($usuario); die();

        if($usuario->num_rows() > 0){
            $user = $usuario->result_array();
            return $user[0];
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

o que retornou com o print_r

```
CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: f373ea5dd5538761406a8022a4b8a374418b240e $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 5 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.6.21 [server_version] => 50621 [stat] => Uptime: 170781 Threads: 1 Questions: 3782 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 315 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 106 Queries per second avg: 0.022 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 634 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 5 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )
```

Comment: ele chega verificar se existe o Login??

Comment: Você consegue saber em que estágio a função está? usando print_r e die()??

Comment: Faça titulos intuitivos ao problema, olhe outras perguntas no site e siga o exempo delas, escrever AJUDA, HELP, PLEASE não faz a pergunta ser mais urgente, todos veem aqui precisando de ajuda, escrever HELP, AJUDA, PLEASE, POR FAVOR é totalmente redundante, seja objetivo ao escrever. Entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se te ajudar, eu uso esta função para verificar o Login:

```
public function verificarLogin(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','valid_email|required|xss_clean|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha','Senha','required|xss_clean|trim');
    $ajax = $this->input->get('ajax');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

        if($ajax == true){
            $json = array('result' => false);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Os dados de acesso estão incorretos.');
            redirect($this->login);
        }
    } 
    else {

        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $senha = $this->input->post('senha');

        $this->load->library('encrypt');   
        $senha = $this->encrypt->sha1($senha);

        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->where('senha',$senha);
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $usuario = $this->db->get('usuario')->row();
        $permissao = $usuario->idPermissao;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM permissoes WHERE idPermissao = '{$permissao}'";
        $permissao = $this->db->query($sql)->row('permissoes');



        if(count($usuario) > 0){
            $dados = array('nome' => $usuario->nome, 'empresa' =>  $usuario->empresa, 'id' => $usuario->idUsuario, 'idCliente' => $usuario->idCliente, 'permissao' => $usuario->idPermissao, 'permissoes' => $permissao, 'logado' => TRUE);
            $this->session->set_userdata($dados);

            if($ajax == true){
                $json = array('result' => true);
                echo json_encode($json);
            }
            else{
                redirect(base_url().'entrega');
            }


        }
        else{


            if($ajax == true){
                $json = array('result' => false);
                echo json_encode($json);
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Os dados de acesso estão incorretos.');
                redirect($this->login);
            }
        }

    }

}
```